# pass Data from Fragment to Fragment but bundle = null

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I know that there are some similar questions but I am new to Android Studio and Java and I don't find the solution for my problem. So the thing is I know that I can pass the data from Fragment one with this code:

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt(key, value);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

And then in my second Fragment, retrieve the data using this:

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if(bundle!=null)
   int myInt = bundle.getInt(key);
```

But my problem here is that my bundle is null and I don't get my value on the second Fragment. What I know is that my problem is probably because of ***Fragment fragment = new Fragment()*** I experimented a bit and did pass a value from my Activity and first it didn't work but then I realized that I had a line like ***Fragment listFragment = new Fragment()*** and then I used listFragment like this:

```
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(key, value);
        listFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

and then I did get my value from my Activity to my second Fragment. So I wanted to ask why this is working on my Activity and not on my Fragment.andr

Comment: we need to see more code how do you setup fragments in your activity .. do you make transactions ?

Comment: pass data like this..

Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
bundle.putString("message", "My Data");
Fragmentclass fragobj=new Fragmentclass();
fragobj.setArguments(bundle);

Try to pass String Key Value pairs...

Comment: In place of this.getArguments(); try to get Data from getArguments();

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
```

You are using the constructor used by the default [FragmentFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentFactory). You want to use the fragment that you have created. For example,

```
Fragment fragment = new FragmentTwo();
```